# The device is temporarily restricted

Tags: usb-debugging, xiaomi

I try to install an app from Android Studio on Xiaomi Mi Max via USB.

The debug mode is on, but when I try to switch the 'Install over USB' enabled, I get 'The device is temporarily restricted' message.

Core version is 3.10.84, Android version is 7.0, MIUI version is 8 Global 7.7.20.

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/xiaomi-mi-note-4-install-via-usb-device-temporarily-restricted/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I got a workaround - the Wi-Fi has to be turned off and then the installation over USB works as expected.

Comment: Thank you!! I really do not understand why that is needed, security feature?

Comment: Welcome, yes, it looks like some SELinux restriction.

Comment: First I had to create the annoying MI account, then it demanded I insert a SIM to allow install over USB, now this... Unbelievably ill-conceived phone.